# Is a continuous function applied to a uniformly integrable sequence uniformly integrable?

Tags: probability, integration

Suppose I have a sequence $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ that is uniformly integrable, that is, the sequence satisfies
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty}\sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}\left[X_i 1_{X_i > a} \right] = 0.
$$
Then, suppose I have a function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and I define a new sequence $Z_i = g(X_i), i \in \mathbb{N}$. What conditions on $g$ are necessary for $Z_i$ to be uniformly integrable? Clearly, if $g$ is bounded, then the result is easy. Is continuity of $g$ enough, if the $X_i$ are unbounded?

Comment: Notice that $X(\omega) = 1/\sqrt{\omega}$ defined on $((0,1), \mathcal{B}((0,1)), \operatorname{Leb})$ is integrable, but $X^2$ is not even integrable. Now set $X_n = X$. Then $\{X_n\}$ is uniformly integrable but $\{X_n^2\}$ is not uniformly integrable.

Answer (score 1):

No, continuity is not enough. Let $X_n=\sqrt n I_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$ on $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure. Then $X_n \to 0$ in $L^{1}$ which implies that $\{X_n\}$ is uniformly integrable. Take $g(x)=x^{2}$. Then $Eg(X_n)$ does  not tend to $0$ even though $X_n \to 0$ a.s.. Hence   $(g(X_n))$ is not uniformly integrable.

Comment: Some condition on the growth of $g$ at $\infty$ like $|g(x)| \leq a+b|x|$ is required for the conclusion to hold.